# Django Rest framework authtoken 'module' object has no attribute 'views'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am learning both Django and the Django REST framework. I had this error before and fixed it. Now, this problem rears its head again.

This is the error I get when trying to get an auth token:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'views'

and this is my `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
import rest_framework
from rest_framework import authtoken
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^games/$', views.GameList.as_view()),
    url(r'^games/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.GameDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

Somehow it can't find `authtoken.views`. Annoying thing is, this worked fine until I restarted with `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work - [`authtoken`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/__init__.py) is a package - when you import it, it does not contain what you want -

```
>>> from rest_framework import authtoken
>>> dir(authtoken)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

You can see that `authtoken` does not contain anything useful. However the view you are interested in is actually inside the [`views`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/views.py) module.

So we can first change the import to:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as authviews
```

Then use it in the urlconf:

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/', authviews.obtain_auth_token),
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? The doc uses the same syntax -- http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: Didn't seem to be sufficient enough for OP ;-) And of course it got downvoted too!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same error, but I realized that below thing.

You need to add `rest_framework.authtoken` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`,
And don't forget to `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Also, take care of order of adding... Add after rest_framework. If u add before it then it will give error. I had this sick issue for 30min :/

Comment: @Omkar i tried this but I'm getting the error: ```AttributeError: module 'rest_framework' has no attribute 'authtokendemo'``` my entry into INSTALLED_APPS is ```[...,'rest_framework', 'rest_framework.authtoken', ...]```